# How can I edit the result of changeStream in loopback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, loopbackjs, loopback

I am using loopback and I need to edit the default result of the `changeStream` in one of my models.

Is there any hook to do this? Something like:

```
MyModel.observe('changeStream', function filterProperties(ctx, next) {})
```

or

```
MyModel.beforeRemote('*', ...);
```

By default i get this response:

```
"{"target":"1234","where":{"id":"1234"},"data":{"$inc":{"counter":1}},"type":"update"}"
```

i want for to count every match with these id and return it

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you want to change?

Comment: @brlebtag question edited to be more specific

Comment: it seems to be a sql problem and not a loopback problem. if you're using mongodb as datasource this may help you: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Comment: its not a sql problem, all works fine, I just wanna change the stream data before its send

Comment: could you give me an example of what result you are expecting?. For me, it seems a sql problem or you're trying to change Server-sent events (SSE) format. Also, don't forget about this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource vs http://caniuse.com/#search=websocket browser support.

Comment: By default, the changeStream, stream you all the updates in your model, so, like in other hooks (before save, before update, etc) i want to do an action before the stream send the last update. And like i said everything works well.